# A timeout is missing in XBee API Python library

Tags: python, xbee

I have a problem with this library:
https://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/

There is the `xbee.wait_read_frame()` function without a timeout.

I am testing all serial ports for a signal, but if i cannot timout a try there is no way to do it.

Is there a posibility in Python to upgrade this function without editing the library?
Or with small changes inside the library?

```
ports_available = []

for port in range(0,20):
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        ports_available.append(port)
        ser.close()
    except:
        pass

print(ports_available)

for port in ports_available:
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        bee = ZigBee(ser)
        bee.at(command=b"MY")
        print(bee.wait_read_frame()) #<----------
        ser.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the asynchronous mode described on page 3 of the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/downloads/detail?name=XBee-2.1.0-Documentation.pdf).  It might be tricky unless the data frame includes a parameter for the serial port that received it.  If it doesn't, you won't be able to connect the data to port that received it.

```
import serial
import time
from xbee import XBee

serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

def print_data(data): """
    This method is called whenever data is received
    from the associated XBee device. Its first and
    only argument is the data contained within the
    frame.
    """
    print data

xbee = XBee(serial_port, callback=print_data)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

xbee.halt()
serial_port.close()
```